# Use 2 arttributes to name 1 attribute in a hierarchy

Tags: ssas, hierarchy

I am working in ssas on a Dimension Hierarchy.

### Dimension:

Dim_Account

ID

Account_Code

Account_Desc

Account_Group_Code

Account_Group_Desc

### Lets say there is 2 levels in the Hierarchy:

Account_Group_Code

Account_Code

I want the names that will be displayed to be the 'Code' followed by the 'Desc' (Description).

### For example:

101-Group1

.....10111-Account1

.....10112-Account2

102-Group2

.....10211-Account3

.....10212-Account4

I can only change it to be either the code or the Description
For example:

101

.....10111

.....10112

or

Group2

.....Account3

.....Account4

What property can I used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to change your SQL view (or named query) on which your dimension is built. Add a field where you're concatenating your code and your description. Use this new field in your dimension.